# Does Delphi support ARMv5 and ARMv6 CPU's?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6, delphi-xe7

Does Delphi support ARMv5 and ARMv6 CPU's and is there a way to make my app work on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no because Delphi compiles native code targeted at a specific CPU, in this case ARMv7 with NEON support.

David I [posted](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2013/09/13/42863#comment-85146) this on the subject:

> Brian Long gives additional Android requirements in his blog post at
>   http://blog.blong.com/2013/09/delphi-for-android-aka-delphi-xe5-aka.html?showComment=1378942045563&m=1
>
> Here is what he lists from our Documentation:
>
> Android requirements
>
> Because the Delphi compiler generates native machine instructions, its
>   output is processor-specific. In other words it doesn’t target the
>   Dalvik Virtual Machine, where regular Android applications reside,
>   which are basically Java p-code applications that are executed by a
>   variant of the Java VM. Instead it generates raw machine code, as all
>   the current wave of Delphi compilers do (the long gone Delphi for .NET
>   was the exception to this general rule). So because it’ a compiler
>   compiling native machine instructions Delphi’s Android support has the
>   following requirements:
>
> there must be a GPU
>
> the CPU must be ARMv7 with NEON instruction support
>
> the OS on the target device must be one of: GingerBread: Android
>   2.3.3+ (MR1 or later), which is API level 10 Ice Cream Sandwich: Android 4.0.3+ (MR1 or later), which is API level 15 Jelly Bean:
>   Android 4.1+ (release, MR1, MR2 or later), which are API levels 16, 17
>   and 18

Embarcadero [clearly states](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) in their manual what is supported.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and what embarcadero tells on the RAD studio road shows), for Android at least ARM v7 with NEON support is required.

Edit: The [(German) data sheet](http://www.embarcadero.com/images/de/pdf/de_delphi_xe7-datasheet.pdf) states "Android-Smartphones und –Tablet-Computer: ARMv7-Geräte mit NEON-Unterstützung," on the bottom of the last page.